# Can I make a code review in TFS without a request?

Tags: tfs, tfs-code-review

Can I perform a code review of my peer's check-in in TFS without an explicit request?

In other words, if I've got a notification about check-in, can I make a comment after having viewed a differences if I feel like they are needed?

I cannot see such an option inside web diff view linked from a notification email. And it looks like there's no mentions about such option and/or workflow in TFS documentation.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2012, go to Source Control Explorer and view the history for an item or folder. When you see the list of changesets, right click one of them and select the 'Request Review' option

Comment: The problem I see with this approach is that you are both the reviewer and the reviewee. The problem is that the reviewer can't initiate the review..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are after [lightweight](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2013-jun-3) [code commenting](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2013-aug-19). This is available now in [TFService](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us) and will be part of TFS 2013 on-premise.

Comment: Do you know if email alerts can be setup for lightweight code comments?  The feature is nice, but out of the box does not alert the checkin originator to comments being made...which seems useless.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Review Assistant](http://www.devart.com/review-assistant/) - an alternative code review tool to built-in one.
It's well-integrated into VS, so you won't experience a major UX shift.

It supports adding "ad-hoc" comments while browsing the code of your peers. And it's not necessary to request a review in this case.